# How to prevent white screen in Video Player after quitting App?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to play a video in my application from my assets file.
I'm using the video_player package for flutter.
Didn't do anything special just copied their implementation from 'flutter.dev', so i'm not going to bore you with the code.

However, my question here is, I noticed when I quit the app (or switch to another app, basically when the app is in the background) and open it again, the video player turns into a white screen and I have to press the play button (FloatingActionButton) again for it to resume.

Any idea on how to prevent this ? I'm running the app on a Physical Iphone X

This is how my video_player is displayed on the Home_Screen:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          FutureBuilder(
            future: _initializeVideoPlayerFuture,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                return AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                  child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
                );
              } else {
                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              }
            },
          ),
          Positioned(
            bottom: 20.0,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
              child: FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    if (_controller.value.isPlaying) {
                      _controller.pause();
                    } else {
                      _controller.play();
                    }
                  });
                },
                child: Icon(
                  _controller.value.isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Thanks

Comment: Where do you instantiate the controller? Are you disposing it too?

Comment: @GabrielMoreyra i'm instantiating the controller in `initState()`, and yes i have a `dispose()` function.

Answer (score 0):

While working with video player package I came across the same problem. Are you checking the resource is truly loaded? Check `_controller.value.isInitialized` within your build method.

Something like this:

```
    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          FutureBuilder(
            future: _initializeVideoPlayerFuture,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                var videoLoaded = _controller.value.isInitialized;
                var widget = videoLoaded 
                    ? AspectRatio(
                        aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                        child: VideoPlayer(_controller))
                    : Container(child:(Text("loading")));
                return widget;              
              } else {
                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              }
            },
          ),
          Positioned(
            bottom: 20.0,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
              child: FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    if (_controller.value.isPlaying) {
                      _controller.pause();
                    } else {
                      _controller.play();
                    }
                  });
                },
                child: Icon(
                  _controller.value.isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```